# Isometry and gluing between smooth manifolds - some references

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have a doubt that assails me.
The technique of gluing along edges between manifolds is generally considered in the topological context.
I don't know if there are other gluing techniques.
I was wondering if there were theorems regarding the possibility of obtaining smooth gluing between isometric manifolds to each other.
That is, if there is an isometry between two smooth manifolds (even local, not necessarily global), is there always at least one way to glue them so that the resulting manifold is still smooth?

Could you give me some information about it and possibly point out some references?

Comment: I suppose you mean an isometry between boundaries of Riemannian manifolds. This works if the boundaries are totally geodesic.

Comment: @ThiKu - yes, I suppose an isometry between boundaries (sorry for my inaccuracy)..so if they are totally geodesics then is the gluing smooth? Thank you for your answer

Comment: We don't need to have an isometry of a metric. If I remember correctly, Milnor's work on exotic spheres shows that we can glue two closed balls in Euclidean space by any orientation reversing diffeomorphism of their boundaries and obtain a smooth structure, without using any metric.

Comment: @Ben McKay - Many thank for your answer! excuse my stupid question, but does Milnor's work hold true for any smooth manifolds?

Comment: @AlexanderPigazzini: I think it is an excellent question. I don't know anything about surgery theory, which is the name for these gluing techniques, but C.T.C. Wall has a beautiful book called Differential Topology which, I think, introduces surgery theory.

Comment: @Ben McKay - Thank you very much!!

Comment: If you are just interested in smooth structures (rather than Riemannian metrics) it is enough to have a diffeomorphism of boundaries, no need for an isometry.

Comment: These smooth gluing theorems are also in Kosinski's "Differential Manifolds".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let (Mi)i=1,2 be smooth manifolds with boundary, Ni ⊆ ∂Mi unions of connected components of the boundaries of M1 and M2, respectively, and φ : N1 → N2 a diffeomorphism. Then there exists a smooth structure on the space M1 ∪φ M2 that arises by gluing M1 to M2 along N1 ≃ N2. This structure is unique up to a diffeomorphism that leaves all points from the original boundaries of M1 and M2, including N1 ≃ N2, fixed.

This statement is copied from http://awgd.org/talks/morse/notes2.pdf , the reference given there is Munkres “Elementary Differential Topology”.

Comment: Thank you very much!!